# Reverse the order of animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, reverse

I am using jQuery to fade in a group of list items, at the moment it is fading from top to bottom; **I would like to fade in from the bottom upwards**.  The function is fired when the bottom most list item is visible in the browser.

[An example is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HxFfH/2/)

Due to constraints I can't simply flip the lists order around, is this possible?

I have read about a possible

```
.reverse()
```

option, but haven't found a way to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your following code:

```
$(".chart.electric li, .chart.fuel li").each(function (index)
```

for this one:

```
$( $(".chart.electric li, .chart.fuel li").get().reverse() ).each(function (index) {
```

See [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HxFfH/14/)

Answer (score 0):

try this .. adding reverse to your each

http://jsfiddle.net/HxFfH/12/

```
    jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

    $(".chart.electric li, .chart.fuel li").reverse().each(function (index,el) {
        $(el).delay(100 * index).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
    });
```